# Using get field to return text

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm writing a contact form for WordPress which also process the contact form and in it I want the e-mail and subject field to come from a field in the WordPress contact page I have created that has a custom field. The line of code I am using is;

```
$email_subject = '<?php the_field(contact_email_subject_message); ?>';
```

But when the e-mail comes through the subject line simply shows the code between the single quotes and not the actual value. I've used this method in other places throughout the site and it's worked fine but not here. I've tried messing about with the quotes, adding echo etc but it either just return the code or nothing or stopping the page working.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: You are assigning a PHP variable, and then trying to further interpret a PHP script inside of it?  Why not just `$email_subject = the_field(contact_email_subject_message);`?  Also, anything inside single-quotes will always be 'as-is' in PHP, as it isn't parsed.

Comment: I tried this, and now it shows the email subject as plain text in the top left of the page, and even if I try to submit the for the subject line is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the Advanced Custom Plugin to store data in custom fields.
The code

```
$email_subject = '<?php the_field(contact_email_subject_message); ?>';
```

did not work, Jon posted I should use;

```
$email_subject = the_field(contact_email_subject_message);
```

Which also did not work, but after some more research I found that if instead of using the_field i used the alternative get_field it would work and thus it did.

Thanks tt Jon for pointing me in the right direction.